# Cambios en docker-compose.yml no funcionan

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Creé un docker-compose.yml con los servicios de php, nginx y mysql, en el servicio de mysql declaré una base de datos pero por inexperto olvidé el charset, entonces entro al container de mysql, borro la base de datos, agrego el charset al servicio mysql:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mibase
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mipassword
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - /io:/home
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Corro de nuevo **docker-compose up** -d pero no crea la base.

Pruebo con 
**docker-compose build --no-cache** y **docker-compose up --force-recreate**
y tampoco hay cambios.

Volví a sacar la línea del charset, y tampoco crea la base.

Comment: cuando corres el build, en el log no ves que se ejecute el command de mysql?

Comment: No, pero devuelve algo como esto: [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch in the column name table_name.  Please run mysql_upgrade